# Understanding SwiftData and bindings/updates, a bare bones example

Tags: ios, swiftui, swift-data

Doing [this code-along](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10154), I'm trying to verify what little understanding I have of SwiftData by making a bare bones example.

This works:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct WWPDApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                
        }
        // this makes modelContext available in the app
        .modelContainer(for: Memo.self)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    // for getting swiftdata
    @Query private var memos: [Memo]
    // for setting swiftdata
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Button("ADD MEMO") {
                modelContext.insert(Memo(name: "new memo"))
            }
            List(memos) {memo in
                Text(memo.name)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

// Putting "@Model" here makes this class work with swift data
@Model
final class Memo {
    
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
    
}
```

That works and verifies that we can add new objects and they are saved.

However, I would like to verify and understand the editting/binding aspect.

I understand that the modelContext is only used for inserting a new object.  For editting an existing object, we are to rely on two way bindings with an object contained in the queried array(?)...

So I tried this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // for getting swiftdata
    @Query private var memos: [Memo]
    // for setting swiftdata
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    
    var body: some View {
        
        // need to put some kind of @Bindable thingy here
        
        VStack {
            Button("ADD MEMO") {
                modelContext.insert(Memo(name: "new memo"))
            }
            List(memos) {memo in
                TextField("this doesn't work", text: memo.$name)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Model final class Memo ...` enables change tracking for the class by adding conformance to the `Observable` protocol. So when you want a binding eg for `memo.name` you could use a `@Bindable`
as shown in the example code.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // for getting swiftdata
    @Query private var memos: [Memo]
    // for setting swiftdata
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("ADD MEMO") {
                modelContext.insert(Memo(name: "new memo"))
            }
            List(memos) { memo in
                @Bindable var memo = memo  // <--- here
                TextField("this works", text: $memo.name)  // <--- here
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's so strange I swear I tried that... but I must have done something else wrong.